# Error when i try to play two sound by media

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I try to play two sound but this is an error at the end of the second sound. I tried to debug but i don't found any thing show me my problem.

Here my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private MediaPlayer mp;
private int[] sound = new int[2];
private int currentSound = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        sound[0] = R.raw.sound_one;
        sound[1] = R.raw.sound_two;
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, sound[currentSound]);
        mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {
                if (currentSound < sound.length) {
                     currentSound++;
                     arg0 = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),sound[currentSound]);
                     arg0.setOnCompletionListener(this);
                     arg0.start();
                }
        }
    }
});
mp.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When first sound completes, `currentSound < sound.length` implies `0 < 2` similarly after completion of second sound `currentSound < sound.length` implies `1 < 2` and further it is incremented by `currentSound++` so now its value is `2`. Hence `arg0 = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),sound[currentSound]);` will throw an error. `sound[currentSound]` is `sound[2]`.

Move `currentSound++` before `if (currentSound < sound.length)`

```
@Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {
            currentSound++;
            if (currentSound < sound.length) {                   
                 arg0 = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),sound[currentSound]);
                 arg0.setOnCompletionListener(this);
                 arg0.start();
            }
    }
```